# Self signed kernel 15.16.10 no longer boots: modules missing, firmware updated

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, firmware

I wanted to try the `5.16` kernel and [signed it myself following some instructions](https://gloveboxes.github.io/Ubuntu-for-Azure-Developers/docs/signing-kernel-for-secure-boot.html) and it worked great for a few days, I could reboot and did so a fair few times.
Then today I got to the stage where I should type in my luks volume password (I use full disk encryption) and got `cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device UUID=[snip]` and it's stuck there.

Managed to boot back in `5.15` just fine.
After searching for that error I saw I could run `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` but that is where my my question comes, I'm getting the following back;

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.16.11-051611-generic.signed
W: missing /lib/modules/5.16.11-051611-generic.signed
W: Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/5.16.11-051611-generic.signed: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
cat: /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_vSN8Oe/lib/modules/5.16.11-051611-generic.signed/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_vSN8Oe/lib/modules/5.16.11-051611-generic.signed: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_vSN8Oe/lib/modules/5.16.11-051611-generic.signed: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-18-generic

[..snip.. no errors on the other kernels..]
```

How can I mend this? Looking at my update history I see I've updated linux firmware before I last powered off the PC `1.187.26` -> `1.187.27`

This is a `Linux Mint 20.3` if it makes any difference.

Comment: It looks like you deleted your modules, so just rebuild your kernel.

Comment: I re-installed it but that didn't help, I've not deleted anything, it got to be something to do with that `linux-firmware` installation or whatever steps happen after that like `update-initramfs` perhaps